# How to define a subclass with Python3 C API using Py_LIMITED_API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

How can I defined a subclass class with the Python C API whose superclass is from a pure Python module?

Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/newtypes.html#subclassing-other-types) mentions that you can define a PyTypeObject that inherits from other PyTypeObject but doesn't mention anything about working with pure python classes.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50039420) shows a way to define a python class from the C API, but it uses PyInstanceMethod_New which isn't available when PY_LIMITED_API is defined.